# How to get the size of a list when write to an file by bytes in python?

Tags: python, list, size

I have a file - which I read it into memory as a list, then split the list based on some rule, say there is list1, list2, .., listn. Now I want to get the size of each list, and this size is the file size when this list write to a file. the following is a code I have, the file name is 'temp', which size is: 744 bytes.

```
from os import stat
from sys import getsizeof
print(stat('temp').st_size) # we get exactly 744 here.
# Now read file into a list and use getsizeof() function:
with open('temp', 'r') as f:
chunks = f.readlines()
print(getsizeof(chunks)) # here i get 240, which is quite different than 744.
```

since I can't use getsizeof() to directly get the file size (on disk), so once i get the split list, i have to write this list to a tmp file:

```
open('tmp','w').write("".join(list1))
print(stat('tmp','w').st_size) # Here is the value I want.
os.remove('tmp')
```

this solution is very slow and require a lot of write/read to disk. Is there any better way to do? thanks a lot!

Comment: I suspect there might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Can you tell us *why* you want to know the disk file size before writing the file to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a series of bytes to a file and then looking at the file length<sup>1</sup>, you could just check the length of the string that you would have written to the file:

```
print(len("".join(list1)))
```

Here, I'm assuming that your list contains byte strings.  If it doesn't, you can always encode a byte string from your unicode string:

```
print(len("".join(list1).encode(your_codec)))
```

which I think you would need for `write` to work properly anyway in your original solution.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Your original code could also give flaky (wrong!) results since you never close the file.  It's not guaranteed that all the contents of the string will be written to the file when you use `os.stat` on it due to buffering.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! It looks similar, but not 100% precise. Do you have any idea what's the reason? In my 744bytes example, it get 700 instead of 744.

Comment: I don't know the reason without knowing what the input file actually looks like.  Is the data in list1 bytes or unicode?  Are you on python2.x or 3.x?  Does the original file have spaces which you're removing?  Was the original file written on windows and you're on unix reading/writing the file with universal newlines?  There are lots of things that could go wrong, but if the second bit of code in your example produced the correct output, I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't either.

Comment: It's a very simple txt file - can be opened directly to read. I have tried: "\n".join(chunks)", which will give me a more precise data - 743bytes. It does works but I have no idea 1bytes less.

Comment: You are getting 700 instead of 744 because you use Windows and your file is 44 lines long. The strings have `\n` as their final character, which is translated by `\r\n` when it is written to the file. If you **know** that your program runs on Windows, then you can try `print(len("".join(list1))+len(list1))`

Comment: My py is running under windows. Thanks, this gives me the correct number I want. :)